# iPhone - 2 instances of same App

Tags: ios, ios5

I have an app on my iPhone that was built on iOS 5 and deployed via Xcode. I recently upgraded Xcode so that I can now build on iOS 5.1. When I go to deploy the app, which still targets iOS 5, it installs a new instance of that app instead of overwriting old one. So now I have the same app twice on the phone.

Why did this occur and how can I prevent it? My app stores user data and that gets lost since it does not overwrite.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for new one you set deployment target 5.1 (and I am assuming that you would not have downloaded earlier sdk again from Xcode->Preferences->downloads) hence its running new instance of an app on your iphone as well as old one that you created on earlier Xcode version with the 5.0 ios sdk.

Comment: So this isn't something I have to worry about when deploying to App store? A user isn't going to upgrade to new iOS and have ability to install same app twice. FYI, when deploying the app under iOS 5.0 simulator it does overwrite old app. So it was only when deploying to a real iPhone I saw this happen.

Comment: That is correct, as long as your bundle id... com.yourname.yourappname  stays the same, when the user updates the app it will override the old one.